# User, currency or language must not be empty

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I am getting the below error while trying to run a cronjob, this seems some database error.

```
User, currency or language must not be empty.
```

Please help.

Comment: It's impossible to help you if you do not provide some code and context... Please try to elaborate your question. Thanks

Comment: agree with @alain.janinm .. but this sounds like you probably need to set at least one of those attributes on your cronjob instance for it to be able to execute.

Answer (score 1):

A Cronjob session needs to have :

- a user to execute the cronjob (admin or other). This will impact what can the cronjob do
- a currency (USD or other). This will impact price calculation if any
- a language (en or other). This will impact the attributes returned by the model

You see this exception because these 3 attributes are mandatory to save a new Cronjob model.